# how can a single command take stdin in one program and filename in other

Tags: bash, sudo, cmdline-args

What i'm trying to do is pass argument into the second program in such a way that it takes cmdline-args and is opened with sudo but doesn't have anything to with stdin that i pass to sudo.

Below is an example to understand what i'm trying to do.

```
echo "mypass" | sudo -S nvim "filename"
```

Here sudo must take stdin and nvim must take a file-name from cmdline-arg. But nvim opens an unnamed file and puts stdin into that file and doesn't even care about the args i pass to it.

My end goal is not to only open file without entering password but to understand how can i pass arguments the way i want to

Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you `echo "mypass" | sudo -S nvim "$1"`? And, by the way, do you know `sudoedit`?

Comment: @mumboFromAvnotaklu : AFIK, `sudo` does not read from stdin.

Comment: @user1934428 This is what I thought too. As I didn't know the `-S` option the OP uses I had a look at the manual and it says: "_-S, --stdin Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device._" Do you, by chance, know what this means?

Comment: `sudo` will certainly read from `stdin` on most systems, but not for a password. `echo date|sudo su` will read `stdin` for the commands to execute and run `date` as root. The `-S` option does, though.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet i tried putting `echo "mypass" | sudo -S nvim "$1"` in a function but it works once in the terminal and gives the behavior mentioned in question afterwards. This is so weird.

Comment: I get different results depending on whether `sudo` has cached my password. If `sudo` actually needs a password, `sudo` consumes standard input. Vim warns that standard input is not a terminal, but seems to "switch" to the terminal if standard input is closed. Trying again, `sudo` remembers that I authenticated in the last minute or so, and ignores standard input. At that point, `vim` again warns that standard input is not  a terminal, then exits with an error because standard input is *not* EOF.

Comment: The "right" thing to do is ignore `-S`, and configure `sudo` to let you run `nvim filename` without a password.

Comment: @PaulHodges Sudo can read for passwords from stdin with -S flag it works just as expected when the command contains a prebaked argument for example `echo "mypass" | sudo -S nvim newfile.txt"` but doesn't work as expected when passing argument i think it has to do with the way the arguments are passed and probably not a  problem with sudo.

Comment: @mumboFromAvnotaklu I gave it a try in a simple shell script without a function and it worked like a charm. The script contains: `echo 'password' | sudo -p "" -S vim "$1"`. And I called it with `./script.sh foo.bar`.

Comment: @chepner I confirm. If the password is cached, before the timeout, `sudo` does not read the password from `stdin`, which is passed to `nvim`, which complains.

Comment: @mumboFromAvnotaklu Try `sudo -k -p "" -S nvim "$1"`. `-k` invalidates the user's cached credentials.

Comment: Try the `sudo -S bash -c` below with redirection from `/dev/null`.

Comment: @chepner yeah that must be the problem and i thought the problem was with the way i was passing arguments ( I had already what Renaud Pacalet suggested but it didn't work because password was already cached ). Thanks for the help man this caching behavior caused a lot of confusion.

Comment: `functionsudok () { sudo -k;sudo "$@";sudo -K; }
vimf() {
    echo "pass" | functionsudok -S nvim "$1"
}` I figured out how this can be done this works without problem for me. Basically you have to wrap sudo in another function that makes sudo forget cached password

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Your first comment answers my question i just wanted to know how can i pass the arguments like how i described, it didn't work when i tried before but that turned out to be another problem. so can you post your comment as answer so that i can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Done. I also added a note about the `-k` option of `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass the filename as first argument of your script:

```
echo "<your password>" | sudo -S nvim "$1"
```

and call the script with:

```
./script.sh myfile.txt
```

Note that the `-S` option of `sudo` behaves differently depending if the credentials are already cached or not. Better also use the `-k` option to invalidate the credentials:

```
echo "<your password>" | sudo -k -S nvim "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you have it seems like it ought to work.
Maybe try a bash call explicitly. That works even if you need a separate input redirection.

```
$ echo "$pw"|sudo -S bash -c "head -3 < foo"
0
1
2
```

If you need to pass a file argument, maybe explicitly bind your stdin elsewhere.

```
$ echo "$pw"|sudo -S bash -c "head -5 foo </dev/null"
0
1
2
```

Comment: This does work the problem was with sudo caching passwords. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Since `the sudo` password doesn't need to be repeated for two consecutive `sudo` commands, I should issue two sequential commands:

```
echo "mypass" | sudo -S -v 
sudo nvim "filename"         # will not prompt for password this time
```

Explanation: `sudo -v` just updates the credentials of `sudo` without executing any command.

Comment: Since I don't have `nvim` installed, I can't check in case the password was not necessary for the first command, if that unused password goes to `nvim`. With `vim` and `gvim`, I don't have the issue described by Renaud Pascalet above.

Comment: The only thing `nvim`-specific would be what it *does* with input not consumed by `sudo`.

Comment: Also, how long and if `sudo` remembers previous authentication is configurable, so I wouldn't assume that the second line doesn't require a password.